# Integration testing Ember Data model in run-loop

Tags: ember.js

I'd like to use the `visit` helper in order to integration test following route:

```
App.IndexRoute = Em.Route.extend
    model: ->
        App.Movies.find "The Godfather"
```

But my test don't pass, I get:

```
assertion failed: You have turned on testing mode, which disabled the run-loop's autorun.
You will need to wrap any code with asynchronous side-effects in an Ember.run
```

Unfortunately, wrapping it up like this doesn't help:

```
App.IndexRoute = Em.Route.extend
    model: ->
        Em.run =>
            App.Movies.find "The Godfather"
```

(I have also wrapped `@App = Em.Application.create()`)

What's the right way to wrap the code into a run-loop?

I'm using `rc.5` with Karma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the server I was trying to fetch the data from returned a **404** and that caused Ember to assert.

After fixing the server side id turned out that there's no need for `Em.run()` at all.

See GitHub for more information: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/3051

Answer (score -1):

How do you build your data for the test? It's that part (or setting properties) that should be wrapped in an Ember.run.

Using the FixtureAdapter, you should have something like this:

```
Ember.run(function() {
  App.Movie.FIXTURES=[{ name: "the Godfather" }, { name: "Apocalypse Now" }];
});
```